# Connecting email server to my Contact page of web application in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-email

Perhaps it is an easy question but I am new in developing in c#, asp.net. I am building a website and I have some troubles connecting the email server to my Contact page. I've been searching for a long time but I couldn't find a suitabe answer. My controller code is the following:

```
namespace SITEEXEMPLO.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string Name, string EmailId, string PhoneNo, string Subject, string Message)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(EmailId);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("xoinas23@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = Subject;

                string userMessage = "";
                userMessage = "<br/>Name :" + Name;
                userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Email Id: " + EmailId;
                userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Phone No: " + PhoneNo;
                userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Message: " + Message;
                string Body = "Hi, <br/><br/> A new enquiry by user. Detail is as follows:<br/><br/> " + userMessage + "<br/><br/>Thanks";


                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                //SMTP Server Address of gmail
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xoinas23@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
                // Smtp Email ID and Password For authentication
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
                ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contacting us.";
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error............";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

And the HTML code is the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table width="100%;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><strong>SEND EMAIL USING GMAIL ACCOUNT IN MVC</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Name :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtName" name="Name" width="250px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Your Email id  :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txttoaddress" name="EmailId" width="250px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Phone No :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtPhoneno" name="PhoneNo" width="250px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Subject :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtsubject" name="Subject" width="250px"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Message :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Message" id="txtmessage"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Attachment :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" text="Send Message" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This works but not the way I want. By running this code, I insert the information and I receive it on the email inserted on the form, not the email in the code. I want the users to write their own email on the form, and by clicking the button I receive the information on my email. Can someone help me?

Comment: This would require gmail allowing your users to send mails from their account via gmail service. This will never work. The sender needs to authenticate.

Comment: And how can I make that work in my website if I want the users to fill the information needed and then I would receive it in my email box?

Comment: It will exactly work like Michael's answer: You are using your mail account as the sender and recipient and will receive the message containing the collected data.

Comment: But the "mail.From" should be the input of the user.. I don't know If I make myself very clear..

Comment: You cannot have an arbitrary `mail.From` sending via your gmail account. You can deliver `EmailId`only as part of the message. If you insist on having the `EmailId` as part of the message headers, you could put it into the BCC recipient field but I guess you do not want the message being sent to the user.

Comment: I'm not the one who should fill the "email from".. I have a website page that contains a form with "name; Email; Subject" that the user should fill and when they click on "Send" I receive that information in my personal mail.

Comment: If you want to achieve what you insist to do, you need to run your own smtp server picking up those messages AND you need a transport provider allowing your own smtp to relay OR a full blown MX of your own. There is really no added value having the user entered EmailId as the sender. Take a step back and consider the security implications that come with allowing senders address differing from the sending account address.

Comment: Ok thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I believe you want to send an email to xoinas23@gmail.com. To do so, change your code to be the following:

```
mail.To.Add("xoinas23@gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("xoinas23@gmail.com");
```

Right now, you are sending an email to the email address provided by the person submitting the form. With this change, you'll just be sending their information to yourself by using your email address.

Comment: I have a contact page, and the users should fill some information like their names, phone number, email, some text and a button to send that information to email. How can I make that work?